# using xpath to obtain complex values

Tags: xpath

Given the following, I'd like to extract VarVal1, VarVa5 and VarText where FixedVals are, well, fixed :)

```
 <TypeA Attr1="VarVal1">
     <TypeB Attr2="FixedVal2">
         <TypeC Attr3="FixedVal3">
             <TypeD Attr4="FixedVal4" Attr5="VarVal5">
                 VarText
             </TypeD>
         </TypeC>
     </TypeB>
 </TypeA>
```

Notice that the big problem for me is that the context is important. I want the complete pattern. There may be other TypeA nodes, but I'm not interested in their values unless they're followed by

```
    <TypeB Attr2="FixedVal2">
         <TypeC Attr3="FixedVal3">
             <TypeD Attr4="FixedVal4" Attr5="VarVal5">
                 VarText
             </TypeD>
         </TypeC>
     </TypeB>
```

In other words, what I'm interested in is a set of tripletts, each of them in the form of (VarVal1, VarVal5, VarText)

Comment: I missed specifying that TypeA may occure in other places of the text, and I'm only interested in those instances followed by TypeB, TypeC and TypeD with the specific fixed values. I'll edit.

Comment: Does that mean not any `TypeA` element but one containing `TypeB`, `TypeC`, etc.?

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, there may be many TypeA elements but I'm ONLY interested in those that contains TypeB, TypeC etc.

Comment: is there always only one occurence of `TypeB`, `TypeC` and `TypeD` in every `TypeA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These XPath expressions:

```
//TypeA 
 [TypeB[@Attr2="FixedVal2"] 
   /TypeC[@Attr3="FixedVal3"] 
    /TypeD[@Attr4="FixedVal4"]] 
 /@Attr1
```

Then those already posted:

```
//TypeA   
 /TypeB[@Attr2="FixedVal2"]   
  /TypeC[@Attr3="FixedVal3"]   
   /TypeD[@Attr4="FixedVal4"]   
    /@Attr5
```

And

```
//TypeA   
 /TypeB[@Attr2="FixedVal2"]   
  /TypeC[@Attr3="FixedVal3"]   
   /TypeD[@Attr4="FixedVal4"]
```

You could also combine them with `|` union set operator. But depending on the host language, you should better select the `TypeA` elements you want (first expression with out last `/@Attr1` part) and then query each of those to extract the remaining values.

Comment: I think I understand. Does each of those expression return a list with N values, (i.e. ValVar1A, ValVar1B,... ValVar1Z and then ValVar5A, ValVar5B,... ValVar5Z followed by VarTextA, VarTextB...VarTextZ and I have to combine the n'th element from each to crate the n'th triplet?

Comment: @Avi: Yes, you are right! The problem with `|` union set operator is that in mostly every XPath engine will result in nodes sorted by document order, but you won't be sure if some `TypeA` isn't containing some of the others nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a couple of queries for this (could be wrong though)

for VarVal1

```
//TypeA/@Attr1
```

for VarVal5

```
//TypeA
 /TypeB[@Attr2="FixedVal2"]
  /TypeC[@Attr3="FixedVal3"]
   /TypeD[@Attr4="FixedVal4"]
    /@Attr5
```

Think these should do the trick

EDIT - missed VarText!

```
//TypeA
 /TypeB[@Attr2="FixedVal2"]
  /TypeC[@Attr3="FixedVal3"]
   /TypeD[@Attr4="FixedVal4"]
```

Comment: Beware of `text()`, it's sometimes better [not to use it](http://www.xquery.com/tips_and_tricks/using_text_in_XPath.html).

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of that. I will update my answer accordingly